# Nested if else statements to append labels to values

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a column of numbers from 1:1000.  I want to append the label "s" to the front of each number so that the total number of characters in each cell remains the same. For instance, "1" would become "s0001", "15" would become "s0015", "620" would become "s0620", and "1000" would become "s1000".

I have tried to accomplish this using nested `if else` statements, but I keep getting the error that the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.

Here is an example data set and the code I'm using:

```
df=data.frame(code=seq(1:1000))
df$code=
  if (df$code < 10) { df$code=paste("s000",df$code,sep="") } else
    if (100 > df$code & df$code >= 10) { df$code=paste("s00",df$code,sep=="") } else
      if (1000 > df$code & df$code >= 100) { df$code=paste("s0",df$code,sep="") } else
      { df$code=paste("s",df$code,sep="") }
```

I suspect there is an easier way to do this without using `if else`.  Any thoughts?

Thanks!

---

**Solution**

Thanks to Joran!  If x is non-continuous integers:

```
d=data.frame(x=sample(1:1000,500))
d$nc=nchar(d$x)
ddply(d,.(nc),transform,lab = paste("s",paste(rep("0",4-unique(nc)),collapse = ""),x,sep = ""))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how bout `sprintf`?

```
> sprintf('s%04d', c(1,10,100,1000))
[1] "s0001" "s0010" "s0100" "s1000"
```

Comment: @joran I only know cause I had to ask when doing the same thing long ago!

Answer (score 1):

I am 100% certain there's a better way to do this, and I'm a little embarrassed to resort to `ddply`, but this works at least:

```
d <- data.frame(x = 1:1000,nc = nchar(1:1000))
ddply(d,.(nc),transform,lab = paste("s",paste(rep("0",4-unique(nc)),collapse = ""),x,sep = ""))
```

There we go, this is much better, I think:

```
paste("s",sapply(4-nchar(1:1000),function(i) paste(rep("0",i),collapse = "")),1:1000,sep = "")
```

Comment: Sweet.  I have a data frame where x is not continuous integers from 1:1000, so ddply to the rescue!

Comment: @jslefche Unless I've misunderstood you, I think my second solution should work as well. You want something like `max(nchar(x))` instead of the hard coded 4. (And of course replace all the `1:1000` with your vector.)